Issue with publishing scala artifact to sonatype repository using sbt
I'm fac9jng following issue:
[error] (publishSigned) java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)

despite having this in my sbt config:
import xerial.sbt.Sonatype.sonatypeCentralHost
ThisBuild / publishTo := sonatypePublishToBundle.value

I'm using:
sbt.version=1.10.0

and:
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-sonatype" % "3.11.2")


What was the exactly sbt command you run? Could be that you are overriding that publishTo property in another line? Is it possible to share your build.sbt file? Maybe a minimal reproducible example?

Is it possible that you have a multimodule project? ThisBuild was always weird to work with when setting something in several projects.
